# Working with static class variables in Python

Tags: python, oop, class, variables, circular-dependency

Python won't allow me to import classes into eachother. I know there is no "package" solution in Python, so I'm not sure how this could be done. Take a look at my files' codes:

file Main.py:

```
from Tile import tile
tile.assign()
class main:
    x = 0
    @staticmethod
    def assign():
        tile.x = 20
```

file Tile.py:

```
from Main import main
main.assign()
class tile:
    x = 0
    @staticmethod
    def assign():
        main.x = 20
```

I get the error "class tile can not be imported".

Comment: your naming convetion is backwards, use `Tile` for the class and `tile.py` for the file, otherwise it is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

If file A imports file B, and file B imports file A, they would keep importing each other indefinitely until the program crashed.

You need to rethink your logic in a way that doesn't require this circular dependency. For example, a 3rd file could import both files and perform both assignments.

Comment: although I'm with you about avoiding circular imports he could do it using `import Tile` instead of `from Tile import tile`, Python won't import the same module twice if it doesn't have to

Comment: No, but it will be unable to compile certain code depending on the order in which it performs the imports.

Comment: But if all use of the imported modules is within functions/methods, as it would be in this case, then circular imports of modules can work fine.

Comment: Scratch that, wouldn't work, because of the module scope calls to `main.assign` and `tile.assign`.

Comment: So there isn't any way to mimic Java's package solution in Python? By working with variables and methods that are within different files.

Comment: @azonicrider: Python doesn't really have packages like that, but nor do lots of languages, without it being a problem. The issue is that importing a file executes it, and you have circular dependencies in the execution. Good program design (in any language) will avoid such dependencies. See the last paragraph of Ben's answer for ways to address this.

Comment: I understand now. Ben's paragraph made me understand your initial statement better, that my files produce an infinite loop. I'm going to code my program in a way where additional files have only callable methods and assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You have your import backwards and the `from` needs to have the name of the module

```
from Tile import tile
```

Comment: I'm sure you mean `from Tile import tile`

Comment: My files have it that way, I just wrote the code here wrong by accident. Regardless I still get the same error.

Comment: @azonicrider Can you post the full traceback then?

Comment: Excuse my noobness, but I'm not sure what traceback is. Is it the full error message?

Comment: so when you run this in the interpreter it will error and print stuff to your terminal.  copy all those error messages (or traceback) and past it in with your question.  It's a good idea to do this with all your questions.

Comment: Possibly this:   File "C:\Users\Jens\Desktop\Horst\Main.py", line 3, in <module>

    from Tiles import tiles

ImportError: cannot import name tiles



Execution Successful!

Answer (score 1):

Python begins executing Main.py. It sees the import, and so goes to execute Tile.py. **Note that it has not yet executed the class statement!**

So Python begins executing Tile.py. It sees an import from Main, and it already has that module in memory, so it *doesn't* re-execute the code in Main.py (even worse things would go wrong if it did). It tries to pull out a variable `main` from the `Main` module, but the class statement binding `main` hasn't executed yet (we're still in the process of executing the import statement, advice that line). So you get the error about there not being a clsss `main` in module `Main` (or `Tile`, if you started from there).

You could avoid that by importing the modules rather than importing classes out of the modules, and using qualified names, but then you'd fall one line down when `Main.main` doesn't work. Your code makes no sense I'm a dynamic language; you can't have *both* the definition of class main wait until after `tile.assign` has been called *and* the definition of class `tile` wait until after `main.assign` has been called.

If you really need this circular dependency (it's often, but not always a sign that something has gone wrong at the design stage), then you need to separate out "scaffolding" like defining classes and functions and variables from "execution", where you actually call classes and functions or use variables. Then your circular imports of the "scaffolding" will work even though none of the modules will be properly initialized while the importing is going on, and by the time you get to starting the "execution" everything will work.